# getting error : missing filed values while updating cache Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, laravel, next.js, graphql, apollo-client

I am actually implementing ability for a user to make comments.
for this i have made mutation for adding Comment in the backend like this

```
addComment(input: AddCommentInput! @spread): Post
        @create
        @inject(context: "user.id", name: "account_id")
```

Its type as

```
input AddCommentInput {
    description: String!
    parent_id: ID!
}
```

Now at the frontend i am trying to trigger this mutation which is happening successfully but i am unable to update my cache due to given error of missing fields
[image]

code for graphql mutation

```
const NEW_COMMENT = gql`
  mutation NewComment($newComment: AddCommentInput!) {
    addComment(input: $newComment) {
      id
      description
      account {
        id
        username
        image
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

The query for which i am updating the cache

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const POST_DETAIL = gql`
  query POST($id: ID, $post: ID!) {
    post(id: $id) {
      id
      title
      description
      comments_count
      votes {
        upvotes
        downvotes
        has_voted
      }
      account {
        id
        username
        image
      }
      projects {
        id
        slug
        image
      }
      tags {
        id
        name
        slug
      }
      created_at
    }

    replies(post: $post) {
      id
      title
      description
      comments_count
      votes {
        upvotes
        downvotes
        has_voted
      }
      account {
        id
        username
        image
      }
      projects {
        id
        slug
        image
      }
      tags {
        id
        name
        slug
      }
      created_at
    }
  }
`;

export default POST_DETAIL;
```

Schema types for the addComment mutation
[image]

Code for the CreateComment.tsx component

```
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useState } from "react";
import NEW_COMMENT from "../../../graphql/mutations/newComment";
import POST from "../../../graphql/queries/post";


function CreateComment({ isReply = false, setShowCommentBox, parentId }: any) {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const { query } = useRouter();  // getting the id for the post from the url 
  console.log(parentId);

  const [addComment, newComment] = useMutation(NEW_COMMENT, {
    update(cache, { data: { addComment } }) {
      const { post, replies } = cache.readQuery({
        query: POST, variables: {
          id: query.id,
          post: query.id
        },
      });
      cache.writeQuery({
        query: POST,
        data: {
          post: { ...post },
          replies: [addComment, ...replies]
        },
      });
    },
  });

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(description);
    addComment({
      variables: {
        newComment: {
          description,
          parent_id: parentId
        }
      }
    })
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col border-[2px] border-default rounded-lg ">
        <div className="flex gap-2 items-center bg-canvas-inset rounded-t-lg">
          <form className="w-full" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <div className="flex gap-2 items-center">
              <div className="px-3 py-2 w-full ">
                <textarea
                  rows={5}
                  placeholder="What are your thoughts?"
                  name="reply"
                  value={description}
                  onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                  className="bg-canvas-inset text-default border-none p-0 text-sm w-full appearance-none outline-none align-middle resize-none focus:shadow-none focus:ring-0"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="w-full rounded-b-lg py-2 px-3 bg-canvas-default">
              <div className="ml-auto flex gap-2 justify-end">
                {isReply ? (
                  <button
                    onClick={() => setShowCommentBox(false)}
                    className="cursor-pointer text-sm rounded-full text-default-accent font-bold px-4">
                    Cancel
                  </button>
                ) : (
                  <></>
                )}
                <button className="text-sm cursor-pointer bg-btn font-bold rounded-full text-btn px-6 align-middle py-1" type="submit">
                  {isReply ? "Reply" : "Comment"}
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default CreateComment;
```

I am a newbie and doing update for the first time any help would be appreciated.

**NOTE**
*I have checked various articles for the issue like * [mising filed issue github](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/8677)
*but have not been able to results evn after making type POST fields as optional in the grapql.schema file at the backend* but its not working even after fields are not required anymore

code for type POST

```
type Post {
    id: ID!
    title: String
    description: String
    comments_count: Int @count(relation: "comments")
    votes: PostVotes @field(resolver: "App\\GraphQL\\Queries\\Post@votes")
    account: Account @belongsTo
    projects: [Project] @belongsToMany
    tags: [Tag] @belongsToMany
    created_at: DateTime
    updated_at: DateTime
    comments: [Post] @hasMany(relation: "comments")
}
```